# "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

The "example.com" file is broken and cannot be used because its target in sites-available cannot be found [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtPZK.jpg)

Comment: just remove it and create a new one?

Comment: also check if nginx has read permissions for the file.

Comment: @JackSparrow How do I do that? am now to Nginx so can you please give me the commands

Comment: go to console and do `sudo echo -e "Test">> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

Comment: @JackSparrow it said permission denied why?

Comment: then you dont have sudo access i guess.